# Cannot create a multiple polygon in tcpdf

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to create a pdf using php and mysql, i have successfully created one polygon using below code but when am trying to create the second polygon it is unable to create and the previous polygon also disappears

How to create the multiple polygons?

First Polygon

```
$pdf->StarPolygon(94, 110, 39, 90, 3, 0, 1, 'CNZ');
$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 1, 'color' => array(145,191,56)));
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata1, 50, 70, 90, 90, '', '', 'C', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

Second Polygon

```
$pdf->StarPolygon(147, 58, 29, 90, 3, 0, 1, 'CNZ');
$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 1, 'color' => array(145,191,56)));
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata2, 25, 130, 70, 60, '', '', 'R', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `StartTransform` before code for second polygon:

```
// Secodn polygon
$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->StarPolygon(147, 58, 29, 90, 3, 0, 1, 'CNZ');
$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 1, 'color' => array(145,191,56)));
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata2, 25, 130, 70, 60, '', '', 'R', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
$pdf->StopTransform();
```